# How can I update a column in a table where I am using the same table to filter the data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a column here. When I run select statement, it gives proper results. But I am not able to update. Here is the script that I am running....

```
update table1
  set col1 = 0
where col1 = 1 and col2 not in (select col3 from table1);
```

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not allow subqueries to reference the table being updated.  So, use a `left join` instead:

```
update table1 t1 left join
       table1 tt1
       on t1.col2 = tt1.col3
    set col1 = 0
where t1.col1 = 1 and tt1.col3 is null;
```

I also strongly advise you *not* to use `not in` with subqueries.  The `not in` doesn't usually do what you intend when *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.  Hence, it is just a bad practice to use something that sometimes does not do what you intend.